# How can download via FTP all files with a current date in their name?

Tags: perl, ftp

I have a file format which is similar to "IDY03101.200901110500.axf". I have about 25 similar files residing in an ftp repository and want to download all those similar files only for the current date. I have used the following code, which is not working and believe the regular expression is incorrect.

```
my @ymb_date = "IDY.*\.$year$mon$mday????\.axf";

foreach my $file ( @ymb_date) 
{

 print STDOUT "Getting file: $file\n";

 $ftp->get($file) or warn $ftp->message;

}
```

Any help appreciated.

EDIT:

I need all the current days file.
using `ls -lt | grep "Jan 13"` works in the UNIX box but not in the script 
What could be a vaild regex in this scenario?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like you're using any regular expression. You're trying to use the literal pattern as the filename to download.

Perhaps you want to use the `ls` method of [Net::FTP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libnet) to get the list of files then filter them.

```
foreach my $file ( $ftp->ls ) {
    next unless $file =~ m/$regex/;
    $ftp->get($file);
    }
```

You might also like the answers that talk about implementing `mget` for ["Net::FTP"](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=32298) at Perlmonks.

Also, I think you want the regex that finds four digits after the date. In Perl, you could write that as `\d{4}`. The `?` is a quantifier in Perl, so four of them in a row don't work.

```
IDY.*\.$year$mon$mday\d{4}\.axf
```

Comment: It should also be pointed out that "IDY.*\.$year$mon$mday????\.axf" is not a valid regex.  qr// and quotemeta would be also be good things for the OP to read about.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think regexes work like that. Though it has been awhile since I did Perl, so I could be way off there. :)

Does your `$ftp` object have access to an `mget()` method? If so, maybe try this?

```
$ftp->mget("IDY*.$year$mon$mday*.axf") or warn $ftp->message;
```